# naming of Django Foreign Keys in order to request correct column

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using Django (I'm new to it). I want to define a foreign key, and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I have a table called stat_types:

```
class StatTypes(models.Model):
    stat_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now I want to define a foreign key in the overall_stats table to the stat_type id that is automatically generated by django. Would that be the following?

```
    stat_types_id = models.ForeignKey('beta.StatTypes')
```

What if I wanted instead to have the stat_type column of the stat_types table be the foreign key. Would that be:

```
stat_type = models.ForeignKey('beta.StatTypes')
```

I guess my confusion arises in not knowing what to name the column in the second model, in order for it to know which column of the first model to use as the foreign key.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a convention thing: you don't need the "s" => `class StatType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not matter what name you give to FK column name. Django figures it out that it is a ForeignKey and appends `_id` to the field. So you do not need `_id` here. I think this is good enough

```
stat_type = models.ForeignKey('beta.StatTypes')
```

[Doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships):

> It’s suggested, but not required, that the name of a ForeignKey field
>   (manufacturer in the example above) be the name of the model,
>   lowercase. You can, of course, call the field whatever you want.